# How to declare a table variable with existing data in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to declare a table variable in sql server which will have some hard coded values in it.
I tried:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Id int) = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) -- gives error
```

and this didn't work either:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Id int) 
INSERT INTO @TBL SELECT * FROM (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) -- also gives error
```

isn't there any way to create a table with hard coded existing values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax you want is:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Id int);

INSERT INTO @tbl (id)
   VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d0f5ee9f1b647cb898da29713e8694a7) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Ohhhh yeah, I remembered it now, actually had used it this way very long ago. many many thanks

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani: Worth noting is that `VALUES` can be a complete replacement for a `TABLE` declaration, depending on how the table is used (`SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) T(Id)`), especially if it's "hard-coded" (though not necessarily if used multiple times, of course).

Comment: @JeroenMostert yeah I know that, but the reason I'm doing this way is because it is going to be used many many times for tens of queries so I want to be able to easily change it for all. the reason I asked the question was for learning purpose mostly

Answer (score 2):

In case your data is a string

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Id int) 
INSERT INTO @TBL 
 SELECT value from string_split('1, 2, 3, 4, 5',',')

 Select * from @tbl
```